# Pass value from service to activity

Tags: android

I have service class which fetches the GPS location and speedband. I am able to show the value in a Toast in another activity, but I am not able to show in a  TextView. My `ServiceActivity` class contains no xml and my `MainActivity` class contains xml. I want to show `ServiceActivity` value in `MainActivity` TextView.

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service
{ 
 private LocationManager locManager;
 private LocationListener locListener = new myLocationListener();
 static final Double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371.00;

 private boolean gps_enabled = false;
 private boolean network_enabled = false;

 private Handler handler = new Handler();
 Thread t;

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {}
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {}
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {}   
   @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 final Runnable r = new Runnable()
 {   public void run() 
     {
   Log.v("Debug", "Hello");
   location();
   handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
     }
 };
  handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);  
       return START_STICKY; 
 }

   public void location(){
 locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

 try{
 gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
 }
 catch(Exception ex){}
 try{
 network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);    
 }
 catch(Exception ex){}
 Log.v("Debug", "in on create.. 2");   
 if (gps_enabled) {
 locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locListener);
 Log.v("Debug", "Enabled..");
 }
 if (network_enabled) {
 locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locListener);
 Log.v("Debug", "Disabled..");
 }
 Log.v("Debug", "in on create..3");
 }   

   private class myLocationListener implements LocationListener
   {
      double lat_old=0.0;
      double lon_old=0.0;
      double lat_new;
      double lon_new;
      double time=10;
      double speed=0.0;
      @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {   
 Log.v("Debug", "in onLocation changed..");   
 if(location!=null){    
 locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);    
 //String Speed = "Device Speed: " +location.getSpeed();
 lat_new=location.getLongitude();
 lon_new =location.getLatitude();
 String longitude = "Longitude: " +location.getLongitude();
 String latitude = "Latitude: " +location.getLatitude();    
 double distance =CalculationByDistance(lat_new, lon_new, lat_old, lon_old);    
 speed = distance/time;     


 /*Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.this, MainActivity.class);
 String DD = String.valueOf(distance);

 intent.putExtra(USERNAME, DD);
 intent.putExtra(EMAIL,email);
 startActivity(intent);
 */
 Intent intent = new Intent("YourAction");
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 //bundle.put... // put extras you want to pass with broadcast. This is optional
bundle.putString("valueName", "The value you want in the activity");
// bundle.putDouble("doubleName", speed);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), longitude+"\n"+latitude+"\nDistance is: "
   +distance+"\nSpeed is: "+speed , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 lat_old=lat_new;
 lon_old=lon_new;
 }
 }
 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}    
   }   

   public double CalculationByDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
  double Radius = EARTH_RADIUS;
  double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);  
  double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);  
  double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +  
  Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *  
  Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
  double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));  
  return Radius * c;
   }   
}
```

**DeviceMovingSpeed.java**

```
 public class DeviceMovingSpeed extends Activity {
    TextView out;
    private MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        out = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ss);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
         super.onResume();
        myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("YourAction");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        if(myReceiver != null)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        myReceiver = null;
    }


    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 // Here you have the received broadcast 
                 // And if you added extras to the intent get them here too
                 // this needs some null checks
                 Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                 String yourValue = b.getString("valueName");

                 out.setText(yourValue);

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), yourValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // double someDouble = b.getDouble("doubleName");
                 ///do something with someDouble
            }
    }





}
```

**Manifest File**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xyz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceMovingSpeed"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.gpstesting.MyService" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat is showing this result....**

```
07-13 14:21:26.169: D/ActivityThread(3310): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-13 14:21:26.909: D/libEGL(3310): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-13 14:21:26.949: D/libEGL(3310): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-13 14:21:26.949: D/libEGL(3310): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
07-13 14:21:26.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(3310): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
07-13 14:21:26.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(3310): Build Date: 02/25/13 Mon
07-13 14:21:26.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(3310): Local Branch: 
07-13 14:21:26.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(3310): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
07-13 14:21:26.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(3310): Local Patches: NONE
07-13 14:21:26.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(3310): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107 +  NOTHING
07-13 14:21:27.069: D/OpenGLRenderer(3310): Enabling debug mode 0
```

***I am not able to get the value from MyService.java to DeviceMovingSpeed.java***

Comment: Show the stack trace

Comment: do not edit your question ..Keep it as orignal

Comment: Dont,worry i will reverse my question to all original from the beginning....i have edited again but its showing nothing in logcat and mobile..

Comment: where is the code that calls service

Comment: Myservice.java is not giving the correct speed and distance of the GPS .....I tried while I was in bus....its not accurate could you light into it ?

Answer (score 3):

Few ways I am sure, but I would do a local broadcast. Here is the gist of it:

In your service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("YourAction");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.put... // put extras you want to pass with broadcast. This is optional
bundle.putString("valueName", "The value you want in the activity");
bundle.putDouble("doubleName", someDouble);
intent.putExtras(bundle)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then, in your activity:

```
private MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver;

@Override
public void onResume(){
    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("YourAction");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    if(myReceiver != null)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    myReceiver = null;
}

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             // Here you have the received broadcast 
             // And if you added extras to the intent get them here too
             // this needs some null checks
             Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
             String yourValue = b.getString("valueName");
             someTextView.setText(yourValue);
             double someDouble = b.getDouble("doubleName");
             ///do something with someDouble
        }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have the service class continuesly passing the value in toast...and I want to set it in the textview in main class xml id.?

Comment: Whatever your value is, put it in your the bundle I show in the example service. Then, in on receive, set your text view with the data from that bundle.

Comment: Ok so I have the value in double data type ..should I put that value in your code where u mentioned "YourAction".... am I right?

Comment: @KUSHAGRAKHARE Check my update. Notice how I put the value in to the bundle and pass it in to the broadcast. Then, in on receive, get the bundle back out of the intent.

Comment: Ok , tomorrow I will tell from my workplace. ...right now I am in my home.....was thinking about the solution nd not able to sleep....thanks mann will proceed tomorrow.

Comment: Hahaha. ..your green tick is due for tomorrow then.

Comment: @LoyalRayne...Please see to my updated question that..I am not able to get the value from MyService.java to DeviceMovingSpeed.java ?

Comment: any answer other than broadcasting?

Comment: @HanWhiteking you could play around with managing a static instance of your activity and just using accessors on that, but that is advised against.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intents to send data:

`Intent YOURINTENT = new Intent(context, SOMECLASS.class);
YOURINTENT.putExtra("YOURPACKAGE.SOME_IDENTIFIER", "THE_VALUE_GOES_HERE");
 context.startActivity(YOURINTENT );`

Then in the activity:

`Intent YOURINTENT = getIntent();
String example = YOURINTENT.getStringExtra("YOURPACKAGE.SOME_IDENTIFIER");`

Comment: What if the activity is already running, and you want to send info? This would not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your putExtra to your intent you are adding intent itself`.  intent.putExtras(intent);`
You should add bundle in your putExtras not the intent object .
So modify your code as below.

```
     Intent intent = new Intent("YourAction");
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("valueName", "The value you want in the activity");
     bundle.putDouble("doubleName", distance);
     intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Also you missed super implementation of onResume .Add it as first line of your on resume.

```
     super.onResume();
```

You are initializing TextView in Broadcast Dont do that initilize text view in Oncreate

```
 TextView out = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ss);
```

Comment: according to your edit in code its showing error in                          LogCat --                                                                                                07-13 10:59:18.949: E/AndroidRuntime(10542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.gpstesting/com.example.gpstesting.DeviceMovingSpeed}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.gpstesting/com.example.gpstesting.DeviceMovingSpeed} did not call through to super.onResume()

Comment: edited my whole answer according to you....but its showing nothing in logcat as well as nothing value in my device too....

Comment: put the breakpoint in receiver and check whether its called or not

Comment: Is broadcast called or not.Have you tested by putting breakpoint in receiver

Comment: google dude..just add breakpoint in receiver and click debug instead or run

Comment: Could any one check why i am not getting my desired result ?